# Query Limit for

Tags: youtube-api

We are using the below API to fetch the youtube articles:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos

Currently we are not sure about whether there is any limit of characters in query size(ex- we can not send a query which has more than 500  or 1000 characters.)

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#qsp
In the above API, the parameter q which stands for query is not mentioning any specific size of the query which we can send to  fetch the articles.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with the Youtube API.

There's a 1024 character limit for Querystring parameters on GET HTTP requests.

**update:** It appears that's correct for HTML 3, but omitted as a restriction in HTML 4.
Could be server dependent.